# Data Binding broke after upgrade to Play service to 10.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am using **Android Studio 2.3** &
Here is **app level gradle** which is working perfectly with play service **10.0.1**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext {

    retrofitVersion = "2.1.0"
    sdkVersion = 25
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.0'
    playServiceVersion = '10.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion sdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    //    As httpclient is deprecated so we use this one.
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twebexponent.artwork"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion sdkVersion
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.0.17"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//      For the device lower than version 5.0
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

//        For multidex
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
//        For fragment issue non default constractor
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            // Enable ProGuard
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            // Common release options
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false

            // Notice that the default ProGuard file (SDK-provided) also enables optimization
            // Here we also include a third file which disables the logging (see below)
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


        }

        /*debug {
            // We enable ProGuard also for debug builds
            minifyEnabled true

            // Notice that the default ProGuard file (SDK-provided) differs from the release one
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibVersion}"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    For design purpose
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
//    For multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
//    For custom tab
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibVersion}"
//    Firebas push & database & auth and play service location map and cluster(map-util)
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
//    Facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
//    For Retrofit
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:${retrofitVersion}"
//    Show image
//    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
//    Bottom navigation bar
//    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.1'
    //    Gallery library
    compile 'me.iwf.photopicker:PhotoPicker:0.9.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
//    Recycler view
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
//    Commom.net for ftp
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    // FAB
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
//    Paypal
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    //    Image upload
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
//    volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//    Firebase UI
//    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my **project level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now when I change the **playServiceVersion** to **10.2.0** that time data binding error occur. It unable to find all the data binding in all of my Activity and through me a error. Here is the error from **Gradle Console**

```
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ArtListCreatedByActivity.java:24: error: package com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding does not exist
import com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding.CreatedByArtBinding;
                                           ^
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ArtListCreatedByActivity.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    CreatedByArtBinding binding;
    ^
  symbol:   class CreatedByArtBinding
  location: class ArtListCreatedByActivity
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ArtNewsActivity.java:17: error: package com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding does not exist
import com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding.ArtNewsBinding;
                                           ^
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ArtNewsActivity.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    ArtNewsBinding binding;
    ^
  symbol:   class ArtNewsBinding
  location: class ArtNewsActivity
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ChatListActivity.java:20: error: package com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding does not exist
import com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding.ChatListBinding;
                                           ^
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ChatListActivity.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    ChatListBinding binding;
    ^
  symbol:   class ChatListBinding
  location: class ChatListActivity
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ChatPanelPage.java:44: error: package com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding does not exist
import com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding.ChatPanelBinding;
                                           ^
E:\workspace all\studio\New_APA_Project\AllPublicArt\app\src\main\java\com\twebexponent\artwork\ui\ChatPanelPage.java:45: error: package com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding does not exist
import com.twebexponent.artwork.databinding.SingleRowChatPanelMsgBinding;
                                           ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 2.106 secs.
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) started.
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.057 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.ParallelTaskPlanExecutor.process(ParallelTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:256)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:135)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 81 more
```

The interesting thing is I think that it was a error from Gradle version 2.3 but actually I tried to build my code using playservice **10.2.0** to Android studio 2.2.3 Stable version also in Android studio 2.4 perview 3.

Still the error exist. I also check my external libraries all are 10.2.0. So if any one known why this play service problem occur please let me know.

Comment: Relevant: Can you post your *project* build.gradle as well? Unrelated: Apache HTTP is deprecated and will be removed in future version of Android altogether. I can recommend OkHttp 3 or HttpsUrlConnection (which is based on OkHttp 2 since Android 5).

Comment: Yes sure i will update my question soon.

Comment: Data Binding spews a bunch of errors when one error happens. Sift through the errors and hunt for the one that isn't a data binding error to see what caused the problem. It is one of the disadvantages of using an annotation processor for data binding. It seems likely that there was an API change or some other change due to the upgrade.

Comment: I just edit my answer add project level build.gradle

Comment: @GeorgeMount Check my error log i also posted it there is no other error except data binding.

Comment: If that is the complete error log, the only hint I see at a problem is that you aren't receiving any other data binding errors -- only a few missing generated binding classes (note that the directory is there). Would you verify that those layout files are still named the same and have <layout> tags? `chat_list.xml`, `created_by_art.xml`, `chat_panel.xml`, `single_row_chat_panel_msg.xml`, `art_news.xml` -- also search the build directory to see if the Binding java files were created in a different package or not at all.

Comment: Yes it is perfectly working in case of 10.0.1 but whenever I changed my play service version to 10.2.0 that time it create problem of those all classes as well as xml who has used in case of data binding.